# Get html dom - Why "html_simple_dom" find page and "cURL" not?

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

For some reason, some times with **cURL** find the pages but not other times, instead **simple_html_dom** find the page with same url.

For example:

```
$url = http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=search_users&search_query=java&page=7
```

with **cURL** the page is not foud:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close($curl);

if(strpos($content, "404") || $content==""){ echo "**************** PAGE NOT FOUND ****************\n"; return;}
```

but yes with **html_simple_dom**:

```
$content = file_get_html($url);//same url above
```

Comment: Please provide code of how you're calling both instances.

Comment: why don't you use the search api ? https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Searching_for_Videos

Comment: Yes, I used the APIs of Youtube